# send a value from datagridview to radiobutton in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to send a value from datagrideview to radibuttom in DoubleClick event

I'm using this code:

```
private void datagrideview1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.datagrideview1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.Equals("Female"))
        mrb_F.Checked = true;
    else
        mrb_F.Checked = false;

    if (this.datagrideview1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.Equals("Male"))
        mrb_M.Checked = true;
    else
        mrb_M.Checked = false;
}
```

and it does not work for me!!

Comment: Chances are, you may be after `.FormattedValue` rather than `.Value`. `this.datagrideview1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].FormattedValue.Equals("Male")`, Though I agree with @GrantWinney, we don't actually know what is not working

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are you sure the cell index is correct for the value you're looking for? Remember the index is zero-based, so `Cells[5]` is the sixth cell. Also, depending on what you're populating the grid with, you may need to call `ToString()` on the `.Value` before calling `.Equals`.

Comment: @RufusL, no need to call `.toString()` on `.Value` when `.FormattedValue` is available.

Comment: sir @GrantWinney Winney no i didn't i will see it, sir  @blaze_125  `.FormattedValue` not work too, sir  @Rufus L Cells[5] is the exactly the right cell and i triyed with Cells["sex"] not work and show the cach message of try{}.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the first line and find out what the value of `Cels[5]` is. There isn't much we can do if we don't know your datasource for the grid. You may also want to remove the `try/catch` so you can see which line is throwing an exception.

Comment: Can we see the datasource?

Comment: sir @RufusL after removing `try/catch` it shows an error says there is no cell called "sex"?? i don't know why.

Comment: sir @blaze_125 how i can show you my datasource as an imagge or the qeury of SQL Connection ?

Comment: We need to see what is being binded to the DataGridView. Everything you think is relevant. Text based is usually better than images... alot of people like me sit behind firewalls that don't let imgur and the likes to go through.

Comment: the code in datasource preview is this: SELECT  id, fullname, age, sex, date
FROM    wait

Comment: I see a problem right there, ties into a comment made by @RufusL. You select statement queries 5 fields, giving you 5 fields, giving you 5 cells... meaning that visible cell 5, is actually index 4 `Cells[4]` since the index is 0-based.

Comment: i know i just added 5 as an example my cell index is 3 in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158188/discussion-between-nouri-yacine-and-blaze-125).

Comment: i think i figure it out by adding a space as exist in the row space like this "F_____" and "F" not work, so should i convert it to string or what ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fully working sample that deals with the data types I think you are dealing with(based on your SQL query).

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CheckACheckBoxByClickingDataGridView_47102655
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BindingList<dgvEntry> dgvData = new BindingList<dgvEntry>();
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        GroupBox gp = new GroupBox();
        CheckBox chkbx = new CheckBox();
        CheckBox chkbx2 = new CheckBox();
        CheckBox chkbx3 = new CheckBox();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitGrid();
            AddData();
            InitGroupBox();
        }

        private void InitGroupBox()
        {
            gp.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            this.Controls.Add(gp);
            chkbx.Location = new Point(5, 5);
            chkbx2.Location = new Point(5, 25);
            chkbx3.Location = new Point(5, 45);
            gp.Controls.Add(chkbx);
            gp.Controls.Add(chkbx2);
            gp.Controls.Add(chkbx3);
        }

        private void AddData()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                dgvData.Add(new dgvEntry { id = i, age = i + 20, fullname = $"Name{i}", sex = i > 4? "Male" : "Female", date = DateTime.Now});
            }
        }

        private void InitGrid()
        {
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dgv.DataSource = dgvData;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
            dgv.DoubleClick += Dgv_DoubleClick;
        }

        private void Dgv_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgv.CurrentRow.Cells[3].FormattedValue.Equals("Male"))
            {
                chkbx.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                chkbx.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }


    public class dgvEntry
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string fullname { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string sex { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think i figure it out by adding a space as exist in the row space like this "F_____" and "F" not work, so should i convert it to string or what?

Comment: @NouriYacine, I updated my code sample with the data types I think you dealing with. This works locally. If it does not work when you fill it with data coming from your database, then I think you should investigate what data is coming from the DB and code accordingly. If you say there are spaces in the data, then you must account for such spaces when you evaluate the content of the field.

Comment: thank you for your help, i get the point that i need and now i'm confused about selecting your answer as the right answer or not?

Comment: Accept only if my answer actually answered your question. There is no harm in not accepting an answer which only offered you clues to get it to work. I will not be offended if my answer is not selected as the answer. Also, if you did find what was the root cause of your problem, please let us know so that if someone with a similar issue comes to this post, well that person will be able to see how you got it solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void EmpDataGrid_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (EmpDataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.Equals("Female"))
            FemaleRadioBtn.Checked = true;
        else
            FemaleRadioBtn.Checked = false;

        if (EmpDataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.Equals("Male"))
            MaleRadioBtn.Checked = true;
        else
            MaleRadioBtn.Checked = false;
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, i solved by grouping a pair of Radiobuttons. Like if you have 4 radiobuttons (**2 for Gender & 2 for marital status**) you must group one pair to avoid conflict because these button by default only one can be selected at ago. Improve it if i said wrongly.

Comment: this is not a answer, this is a comment. Pls do it at the comment section.